# Android-kotlin-binding doesn't update the properties

Tags: android, binding, kotlin

My problem is the `binding` is work, but not correctly! When I type new text in `textfield` and then try to get data from this `textfield` with help `binding`, I see old data. I tried to find the mistake, but I couldn't.

**My `activity_fblogin.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_main"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.example.darkt.makeyouself.activities.FBLogin"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="test01"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Login"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userPass"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="123456"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userName"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="74dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="245dp"
            tools:text="Password"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/green_main"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/userPass"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userPass" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

It is my `kotlin` class for `fblogin_activity`. I was trying to fixed this problem, but ... Give me idea please!

```
package com.example.darkt.makeyouself.activities

class FBLogin : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var binding: ActivityFbloginBinding? = null
    private var auth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    private var dbHelper: FirebaseHelper? =null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_fblogin)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        dbHelper = FirebaseHelper()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fblogin)

        binding?.executePendingBindings()

        signIn.setOnClickListener{_ -> showSignInActivity()}
    }

    private fun loginToSystem() {
        val email = binding?.userName?.text.toString().trim()
        val password = binding?.userPass?.text.toString()
        binding?.executePendingBindings()

        Toast.makeText(this, email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Toast.makeText(this, password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

[Example mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksShc.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your layout xml that actually uses databinding.

first in your  tag, you will need to define an object to reference for data binding. for example:

```
<data>
   <variable name="user" type="com.myapp.User"/> 
</data>
```

further down in the username/password field you would need to reference this user for the text field

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@={user.username}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userPass"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="@={user.password}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="74dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="245dp"/>
```

Note the @={user.username} in the text field. For every property of the class user, you will need to specify a setter/getter. the @= means, update the underlying object when this value changes.

before your "executePendingBindings" you will need to do something like this:

```
val user = User()
binding.setVariable(BR.user, user)
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

then you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Chris! But it is not working. 20 day ago i asked some question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380992/kotlin-android-binding-not-update-data 
no one answered the question